# How to display SQL result like that

Tags: sql, join

I want to join table Documents(id, name) and Tags(tagId, tagname, docId(FK)). However result will return many redundant rows because one document can has many tags:

```
Document_name |Tag
----------------------
document01     tag01
document01     tag02
document02     tag01
```

All I try to resolve is:

```
document_name |Tags
----------------------------
document01    | tag01, tag02
document02    | tag01
```

or can be like this:

```
Document_name |Tag_1   |Tag_2  |Tag_...
---------------------------------------
document01     tag01  |tag02
document02     tag01
```

Anyone know how can implement this case? Thanks a lot! (I'm trying to find other answer in this site, but I don't know suitable keyword to search in this case)

Comment: [This can be helpfull][1]

I specially like the one with the STUFF clause

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using MySQL you can do this:

```
select document_name, group_concat(tag SEPARATOR ', ')
from Documents
group by document_name
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008, is it have any function like group_concat()?

Comment: MSSQL does not have that function. But you can search on stackoverflow for questions like `group_concat for sql-server` and you will find workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

For MS-SQL try this

```
select 
    d1.Document_name, 
    ( 
        select d2.Tag +','
        from Docs d2
        where d2.Document_name = d1.Document_name
        for xml path('')
    ) as Tags
from Docs d1
group by d1.Document_name
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL:

```
SELECT doc.name, GROUP_CONCAT( tag.tagname SEPARATOR ', ') 
       FROM documents AS doc
       JOIN Tags AS tag ON doc.id = tag.docId
       GROUP BY tag.docId
```

Result:

```
document_name |Tags
----------------------------
document01    | tag01, tag02
document02    | tag01
```

Comment: OP said he was using SQL Server 2008.